# Copy files in subdirs to azure storage with ADF

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I have a folder structures like this:

```
folder1/folder2
               /YearNumber1
                           /monthYear1
                                     /somefile.csv, tbFiles.csv
                           /monthYear2
                                     /somefile2.csv, tbFiles2.csv
                           ...(many folders as above)
               /YearNumber2
                           /montYear11
                                      /somefileXXYYZz.csv, otherFile.csv
                           /monthYear12
                                       /someFileRandom.csv. dedFile.csv
                           ...(many folders as above)
```

**Source:**
Binary, linked via fileshare linked service

**Destination:**
Binary, on azure blob storage

I don't want to retain the structure, just need to copy all csv files.

Using CopyActivity:

```
Wildcard Path: @concat('folder1/folder2/','*/','*/',) / '*.csv'
```

with recursive

But it copies nothing, 0 Bytes.

Comment: Can you eloborate on the source setup and the destination. If I guess, you are having Self hosted IR to access files on your local PC and want to copy them into Azure blob storage. What dataset are you using ? DO you want to retain the hierarchy structure after copy or just want to copy all the csv to a single container ?

Comment: Can you try as this https://i.stack.imgur.com/4NpB7.png

Comment: This are the wildcards I am using

https://imgur.com/a/HwbP5Gc

Comment: oki, you don't have to use concat() function, you can just mention as string and if you see the snip in my answer, I have at the beginning set path in source dataset starting with my filesystem that is `my-filesystem`. Yours seems to be starting with `folder1` , can you check the root path matches

Comment: please try as last comments on my answer

Comment: Was my answer helpful ?

Comment: Ill get back as soon as possible, after testing it :) The data is huge.

Comment: @KarthikBhyresh-MT I tried. It copies all the folders structures.

Comment: At the sink settings, can you try setting property `copyBehavior` to `FlattenHierarchy`

Comment: I have tried, this should work - https://i.stack.imgur.com/HF6dJ.png

Comment: @KarthikBhyresh-MT This is working but it does not retain the names of csv files. It autogenerates the names of the files.

Comment: yes, unfortunately that is by design, filenames are autogenerated, there is no alternate I see

Comment: @Obiii, any luck? I'm having the same issue. I want to copy files in container_a/<user_id>/<some_other_id>/*.csv to container_b/<some_other_id>/*.csv

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the below options in the `CopyActivity` Source Setting:

**1.** `File path type`

Allowed wildcards are: `*` (matches zero or more characters) and `?` (matches zero or single character); use `^` to escape if your actual folder name has wildcard or this escape char inside.
*See official MS docs for more examples in [Folder and file filter examples](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-azure-data-lake-storage?tabs=data-factory#folder-and-file-filter-examples).*

- `wildcardFolderPath` -  The folder path with wildcard characters under your file system configured in dataset to filter source folders.
- `wildcardFileName` - The file name with wildcard characters under your file system + folderPath/wildcardFolderPath to filter source files.

**2.**  `recursive` - When set to **true** the data is read recursively from the subfolders.

**Example:**

[image]

If there are only `.csv` files in your source directories you can simply specify `wildcardFileName` as just `*`

Comment: This is what I have been trying but it shows 0 bytes copied. 

Wildcard Path: @concat('folder1/folder2/','*/','*/',) / '*.csv'

Comment: oki, can you enable logging in copy activity to see if it is reading anything. And also, the path you are providing is apart from the first field for `file-system` right ? so that points to `your-filesystem/folder1/folder2/*/*/*.csv`

Comment: as you want from all the folders under `folder1/folder2/` use `folder1/folder2/**/*.csv`

Comment: no need to use concat

Comment: I tried. It copies all the folders structures.